# How to use split_part function in HIVESql

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql, presto

Here is what i do in prestosql

`select split_part('one|||two','|||',1)`

result = 'one'

but I can't use this function(split_part) in *HIVEsql*

Is there any possible function for me to get the same result as above but in HIVEsql?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this way?

```
SELECT split('one|||two','[\\|||]')[0]
```

The "|" is a reserved character, so you need to scape it properly

Answer (score 0):

Hive does have a `split()` function, but it returns an array.  That would be:

```
select split('one|||two', '[|]{3}')[0]
```